# Filter out common words for search query

Tags: c#, search, stop-words

Are there any easy ways to implement filtering a user's input (possibly a question) by extracting the meaningful data in the query?

I basically want to filter out any noise words so I can send a 'clean' query to Google's search api.

Answer (score 2):

Um, won't Google do this for you?  Send all those dirty, filthy words to Google and let them clean them up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff talked about "stop words" in one of the previous stackoverflow podcasts.  You might try searching for that phrase on google.  The wikipedia page seems to have some overview and pointers to options.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the top X most common English words, but you will always run into trouble with a naive approach like this.

This is because common English words can have special significance in the realm of Computer Science (or other areas). A recent SO podcast ([#32](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/podcast-32/)) mentions this very issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used the stop words approach when implementing a basic search engine and it worked fine.
Try a sample list like the one [here](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/idom/ir_resources/linguistic_utils/stop_words)

Based on feedback from your users, you can modify your stop word list accordingly.